# QT Quick XmlListModel remains desperately empty

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I am new to Qt Quick and I am trying to retrieve a list of video names from a YouTube channel into an XmlModelList. I tried many ideas but the list remains empty.

Here is my code:

```
import QtQuick 2.11
import QtQuick.Window 2.11
import QtQuick.XmlListModel 2.0

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    XmlListModel {
        id: videoListModel
        source: "https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=UCupvZG-5ko_eiXAupbDfxWw"
        query: "/feed/entry"
        XmlRole { name: "title"; query: "title/string()" }
    }

    ListView {
        orientation: ListView.Vertical
        anchors.top: parent.top

        model: videoListModel

        delegate: Component {
            id: videoDelegate
            Text {
                text: title
                width: 200
                height: 50
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In Qt Quick I am confused by the apparent lack of debugging messages. How can I figure out if the problem is with the network connection, the download of the file, the parsing of the file or something else??

Thanks.

Comment: Test with hand written xml. Then verify downloaded xml matches the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are just missing the namespace declarations:

```
    XmlListModel {
            id: videoListModel
            source: "videos.xml"//"https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=UCupvZG-5ko_eiXAupbDfxWw"
            namespaceDeclarations: "declare default element namespace 'http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom';"
            query: "/feed/entry"
            XmlRole { name: "title"; query: "title/string()" }
   }
```

See [namespaceDeclarations](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-xmllistmodel-xmllistmodel.html#namespaceDeclarations-prop)

Answer (score 0):

You may use [errorString()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-xmllistmodel-xmllistmodel.html#errorString-method) method to get

> a string description of the last error that occurred if status is `XmlListModel::Error`.